# Custom Attribute Directive with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my html i have added directive as below

```
<html ng-app="xxxxx" bm-app="auth">
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('xxxxx').directive('bmApp', bmApp);   

bmApp.$inject = ['$document', '$log', 'matchmedia', 'AuthenticatedSession', 'bmUser'];

function bmApp($document, $log, matchmedia, authenticatedSession, bmUser) {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: [function () { }],
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = $document.find('html');

            if (attrs.bmApp !== 'pre-auth') {
                /* load intrinsic post-auth objects */
                authenticatedSession.load().then(function(data) {
                    $log.log('session:', { meta: data.meta, bindings: data.bindings });
                }).finally(function () {                        
                 html.addClass('bm-resolved');
                });
                bmUser.load();
            }                
        }
    };
}
```

I just want to validate whether the user is authenticated or not. If not i need to redirect user to login page using custom directive. I am new to AngularJs, please someone help me to sort this out.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jbrown My question is how to redirect user to login page if not authenticated?

Comment: There a several posts on this site that address different ways of handling this scenarion.  Search 'angularjs redirect to login'